# 15" MacBook Pro Mid 2009 SuperDrive doesn't read burned disks

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have a mid 2009 15" MacBook Pro (5.4), system 10.11.6  and its SuperDrive doesn't read disks that are burnt. Either they are ejected after a while or finder tells me that these are blank disks. However when I insert old install DVDs from Apple (Leopard, Snow Leopard) they are recognized and the installer opens without any problem.
I can't reproduce exactly when it started behaving like that because it's been a couple of years ago when I last time inserted any disk in it, but I remember SuperDrive was reading them without any problem.

I really want to get this fixed because I desperately need a Windows partition for specific software from my work. Unfortunately old models don't support booting from USB.

Comment: Your question reads to me like it's an XY problem. You have a problem (X) and decide the solution is Y, and when you can't quite get Y to work you've come here asking a question about Y rather than X (the original problem). Please correct me if I'm wrong, but your real issue is summarised in your 2nd paragraph, namely that you require specific software for your work. Perhaps you could edit this question to narrow it down to just the SuperDrive issue, and ask another question about how to install the software you need.

Comment: Also, if your statement that _Unfortunately old models don't support booting from USB_ is about the 15" mid-2009 MBP you own, then this model does support booting from USB. You may find my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270076/168832) here useful.